# Jenkins complains compliance errors where as it works fine with POM

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

I am able to run my tests, when I am right click on `pom.xml` and run as Maven test.

After that I configured the same project in Jenkins, but Jenkins failed to build with below error. Can some help me.

```
[INFO] Compiling 17 source files to C:\Users\user\.jenkins\workspace\mavenproj\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/Hooks.java:[28,31] generics are not supported in -source 1.4
  (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/Hooks.java:[28,75] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.4
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/Hooks.java:[35,10] annotations are not supported in -source 1.4
  (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/utils.java:[25,38] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/utils.java:[25,40] not a statement
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/utils.java:[25,44] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/utils.java:[25,45] not a statement
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/utils.java:[25,49] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/utils.java:[25,50] not a statement
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/utils.java:[25,54] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/mavenproj/src/test/java/helpers/utils.java:[145,67] generics are not supported in -source 1.4
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) to set source/target:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

This means you need to fix your project. BTW: Jenkins is not complaining your pom project setup is wrong. Never tested on command line. IDE is something different than command line.